# AWS WAF rule that only accepts requests from my domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

i need help regarding AWS Web Application Firewall rule.

I am putting the JSON down below where I tried to make it like it will accept request from my domain and localhost:3000 only but it doesn't work. Please help me through this

```
{
  "Name": "frontend-asset-allow-enthouse-in-localhost",
  "Priority": 3,
  "Action": {
    "Allow": {}
  },
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
    "MetricName": "frontend-asset-allow-enthouse-in-localhost"
  },
  "Statement": {
    "OrStatement": {
      "Statements": [
        {
          "ByteMatchStatement": {
            "FieldToMatch": {
              "SingleHeader": {
                "Name": "host"
              }
            },
            "PositionalConstraint": "EXACTLY",
            "SearchString": "localhost:3000",
            "TextTransformations": [
              {
                "Type": "NONE",
                "Priority": 0
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "ByteMatchStatement": {
            "FieldToMatch": {
              "SingleHeader": {
                "Name": "host"
              }
            },
            "PositionalConstraint": "EXACTLY",
            "SearchString": "enthouse.in",
            "TextTransformations": [
              {
                "Type": "NONE",
                "Priority": 0
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "accept request from my domain and localhost:3000 only" you appear to be restricting requests *for* your domain and localhost:3000, not *from*.  What do you mean exactly by that phrase?  More generally, what precisely are you trying to accomplish here ?

Comment: @erik258 ok maybe there was some mistake from my end. I want a rule where only my local server i.e localhost:3000 and my domain are allowed to pass through WAF

Comment: you want to accept only requests from websites hosted on those URLs?  CORS is probably the most effective way of doing it, but that wouldn't stop requests, it would just require the client to specify one of those as the Origin URL.  Browsers respect it but nefarious actors can easily get around it